# What do they mean by quantum in GraphicsMagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

> GM has build option quantum which defines the bitdepth to use when
>   reading an image. Building GM with high quantum means that images of
>   smaller bitdepth will take a lot more memory.

What is the ***quantum*** here? Can anyone give me some resources about this?

Answer (score 7):

It is a build-time setting, which means you need to recompile **GraphicsMagick** in order to change it.

If you build with `Q8`, each of your pixels in an image can have 2^8 unique values, i.e. 256 shades of grey.

If you build with `Q16`, each pixel can have 2^16 unique values - i.e. 65,536 shades of grey.

So, with a larger quantum setting, on the plus side, you will get smoother gradients, and less rounding errors, for example. The downside is that your processing may take longer (CPU-dependent) and will take more RAM to store it.

You can check your current setting with:

```
gm identify version
```

**Sample Output**

```
GraphicsMagick 1.3.27  Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2017 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     yes
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 yes
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     no
  JPEG-2000                no
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               no
  Loadable Modules         yes
  OpenMP                   no
  PNG                      yes
  TIFF                     yes
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     no
  WMF                      no
  X11                      no
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes

Host type: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0

Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.27' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-modules' '--without-lzma' '--disable-openmp' '--with-quantum-depth=16' '--without-gslib' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts' '--without-x' '--without-lcms2' 'CC=clang' 'CXX=clang++'

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = clang
  CFLAGS   = -g -O2 -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE
  CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
  CXX      = clang++
  CXXFLAGS = -D_THREAD_SAFE
  LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/lib
  LIBS     = -lfreetype -lbz2 -lz -lltdl -lm -lpthread
```

The very first line has `Q16` in it, meaning my Quantum is 16.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Color.html), quantum is:

> The base type used to represent color samples in GraphicsMagick is the
>   Quantum type. Pixels are represented by a structure of Quantum values.
>   For example, an RGB pixel contains red, green, and blue quantums,
>   while an RGBA pixel contains red, green, blue, and opacity quantums.
>   The maximum value that a Quantum can attain is specified by a constant
>   value represented by the MaxRGB define, which is itself determined by
>   the number of bits in a Quantum. The QuantumDepth build option
>   determines the number of bits in a Quantum.